# Trace Perl Method Calls

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a good Perl library that will trace method calls and dump them to a file as a program executes.

I know of [Devel::Trace](http://p3rl.org/Devel::Trace) but it is quite limited and the output is super verbose.

Is there something better out there?

I'd like to be able to run something like the following from CLI.

```
perl -MTracer("My::Package::*", my_trace_file) my_large_modularized_program.pl
```

Ideally that would dump a list of method calls made in `My::Package` out to the file `my_trace_file`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried googling for "perl trace sub calls". The first two hits seem appropriate:
[Debug::Trace](http://p3rl.org/Debug::Trace) and [Debug::LTrace](http://p3rl.org/Debug::LTrace).

Comment: The desired tool is `perl -MDebug::LTrace='*' your_program.pl` which logs all method calls

Answer (score 3):

Use a profiler. [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://p3rl.org/Devel::NYTProf) is pretty much defacto standard for that.